# Openstack VM instance SHUTOFF after few minute

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-nova

For learning purpose i have build `openstack` on `VirtualBox` with 2 vCPU and 4GB Memory. It installed successfully and i am able to start VM instances but what happened is guest VM got `SHUTOFF` status after few minutes. I have google this issue but didn't get proper answer. I have check logs and i didn't find anything suspicious.

- How do i check VM console so i can see what is going on there?
- Where should i check SHUTOFF specific error logs, i meant in which file?

**EDIT:**

Following is output of `nova console-log` but it stuck there not going ahead and i can't see login screen too

```
openstack@openstack1:~$ nova console-log 970a3722-0fb3-4db6-862b-2aa626cc68a8
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.0.0-12-virtual (buildd@crested) (gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) ) #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 18:19:02 UTC 2011 (Ubuntu 3.0.0-12.20-virtual 3.0.4)
[    0.000000] Command line: LABEL=cirros-rootfs ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0 console=hvc0
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009dc00 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009dc00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000001fffd000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000001fffd000 - 0000000020000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] DMI 2.4 present.
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x1fffd max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fdaf0] fdaf0
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-000000001fffd000
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 1fdf9000 - 1ffed000
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fd990 00014 (v00 BOCHS )
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 000000001fffd7b0 00034 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 000000001fffff80 00074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 000000001fffd9b0 02589 (v01   BXPC   BXDSDT 00000001 INTL 20100528)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 000000001fffff40 00040
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000001fffd910 0009E (v01 BOCHS  BXPCSSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 000000001fffd830 00072 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 000000001fffd7f0 00038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCHPET 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at 0000000000000000-000000001fffd000
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-000000001fffd000
[    0.000000]   NODE_DATA [000000001fff5000 - 000000001fff9fff]
[    0.000000] Zone PFN ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000010 -> 0x00001000
[    0.000000]   DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node
[    0.000000] early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000010 -> 0x0000009d
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000100 -> 0x0001fffd
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x01] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 1, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] SMP: Allowing 1 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009d000 - 000000000009e000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009e000 - 00000000000a0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
[    0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at 20000000 (gap: 20000000:dffc0000)
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:64 nr_cpumask_bits:64 nr_cpu_ids:1 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 27 pages/cpu @ffff88001fa00000 s79296 r8192 d23104 u2097152
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129157
[    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: LABEL=cirros-rootfs ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0 console=hvc0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Checking aperture...
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] Memory: 497852k/524276k available (6206k kernel code, 460k absent, 25964k reserved, 6907k data, 900k init)
[    0.000000] SLUB: Genslabs=15, HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:4352 nr_irqs:256 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.000000] allocated 4194304 bytes of page_cgroup
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.000000] Fast TSC calibration failed
[    0.000000] TSC: Unable to calibrate against PIT
[    0.000000] TSC: using PMTIMER reference calibration
[    0.000000] Detected 2486.018 MHz processor.
[    0.024490] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4972.03 BogoMIPS (lpj=9944072)
[    0.025939] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.029903] Security Framework initialized
[    0.033041] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.033539] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.037514] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.039560] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.040693] Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
[    0.054301] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.054957] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.056108] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.056838] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.057341] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.057824] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.058338] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.060182] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
[    0.062116] SMP alternatives: switching to UP code
[    0.236105] Freeing SMP alternatives: 24k freed
[    0.237129] ACPI: Core revision 20110413
[    0.270578] ftrace: allocating 26075 entries in 103 pages
[    0.289821] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.332667] CPU0: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.0 stepping 03
[    0.336020] APIC calibration not consistent with PM-Timer: 103ms instead of 100ms
[    0.336020] APIC delta adjusted to PM-Timer: 6249961 (6456813)
[    0.336020] Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
[    0.341160] Brought up 1 CPUs
[    0.341596] Total of 1 processors activated (4972.03 BogoMIPS).
[    0.348508] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.370265] print_constraints: dummy:
[    0.370818] Time: 22:32:35  Date: 07/31/13
[    0.373184] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.377862] ACPI: bus type pci registered
[    0.379805] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.394436] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.441293] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.441749] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.442853] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.504949] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.505458] HEST: Table not found.
[    0.505922] PCI: Ignoring host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=use_crs" and report a bug
[    0.508456] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.514427] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[    0.515222] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb100-0xb10f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
[    0.526520]  pci0000:00: Unable to request _OSC control (_OSC support mask: 0x1e)
[    0.612644] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    0.614063] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    0.615312] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    0.616918] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    0.618197] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs 9) *0
[    0.622888] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.623734] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.624235] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    0.627513] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.629754] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.630590] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.632126] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.634610] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.640771] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.641144] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.641570] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.642769] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.744929] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.746522] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.748377] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
[    0.761838] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
[    0.762440] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    0.791325] Switching to clocksource acpi_pm
[    0.791325] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.792984] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #0
[    0.794980] IP route cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.800380] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.802008] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.803089] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    0.803751] TCP reno registered
[    0.804373] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.805192] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.806852] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.807530] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    0.808586] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    0.809327] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    0.816560] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.817591] type=2000 audit(1375309954.816:1): initialized
[    0.903327] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.928384] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.929484] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.938210] fuse init (API version 7.16)
[    0.940982] msgmni has been set to 972
[    0.949280] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    0.950562] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.951008] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.951941] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.955245] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.956970] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.960881] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
[    0.962211] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.979110] ERST: Table is not found!
[    0.982891] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11
[    0.983651] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
[    0.986746] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 10
[    0.987395] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
[    0.993533] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.017633] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 10
[    1.018210] virtio-pci 0000:00:05.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
[    1.020389] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.052583] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.082516] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.165489] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.244653] 00:06: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.248018] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[    1.249922] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    1.279474] brd: module loaded
[    1.287981] loop: module loaded
[    1.597690]  vda: vda1
[    1.624125] Freeing initrd memory: 2000k freed
[    1.626790] scsi0 : ata_piix
[    1.629007] scsi1 : ata_piix
[    1.629910] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc0a0 irq 14
[    1.630652] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc0a8 irq 15
[    1.636489] Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.637469] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.638209] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.638756] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>

openstack@openstack1:~$
```

Comment: What are you using to log into VM? I think for the time VM is on, you can do SSH to the floating IP that you must have got. And roughly monitor the processes on that VM which is making it SHUTOFF. Doesn't seem to be an issue on OpenStack side.

Comment: Did you ever remedy this question? I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can get guest console on the dashboard or with this command:

```
nova get-vnc-console <instance id> novnc
```

If your guest image redirects console messages (like the ubuntu cloud image), you can see boot messages on dashboard or with the command:

```
nova console-log <instance id>
```

You may get clues in /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log and in your hypervisor logs (/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log for QEMU/KVM).

A possible cause is that your guest can't boot on its primary disk and get stuck on boot sequence. Try other images, like [the ones proposed in OpenStack documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-image/content/ch_obtaining_images.html).

Comment: I have tried other images to like 1cirros-0.3.0-x86_64-disk.img` but still no luck if i can see console logs then i can do something

Comment: I have edit my question and paste console-log output but it seem it stuck at `tun` and not moving ahead

Comment: What hypervisor are you using?Try first to launch a VM directly with your hypervisor outside of OpenStack, it will confirm if the issue comes from openstack misconfiguration or if it's a virtualization problem.

Comment: Outside OpenStack my VM works if i directly launch using qemu